# Checking whether it is some falsy value or something

Tags: ruby

Is there a short way to write the following (so that `x` appears only once)?

```
x == nil or x == something
```

An important thing is that calling `something` is not done when `x == nil` is satisfied. The possibility of `x` being `false` does not need to be considered.

Comment: Won't `x == (nil || something)` work in this case? Or I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @User089247 `x == (nil || something)` is equivalent to `x == something`.

Comment: @MarekLipka : Thanks. Then I see no point of checking if `x == nil`.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid referencing `x` twice (I can't prove it), but you can write it a bit shorter: `!x || x == something` and `x == (x && something)` should be equivalent.

Comment: @Stefan That is the best solution, I think. Would do you like to make that into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead `x == nil` you can test `x.nil?`.

So you could use:

```
x.nil? or x == something
```

or

```
x.nil? || x == something
```

The solution with `include?` needs an additional array, depending on your report it may need some additional workload (but I think that is unnecessary microtuning)

Nevertheless, here's a benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

TEST_LOOPS = 10_000_000
X = nil
Y = :something
Z = :something_else

Benchmark.bm(20) {|b|

  b.report('nil? or') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      X.nil? or X == :something
      Y.nil? or Y == :something
      Z.nil? or Z == :something
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('nil? ||') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      X.nil? || X == :something
      Y.nil? || Y == :something
      Z.nil? || Z == :something
   }            #Testloops
  }

  b.report('== nil or') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      X== nil or X == :something
      Y== nil or Y == :something
      Z== nil or Z == :something
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('== nil ||') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times{ 
      X== nil || X == :something
      Y== nil || Y == :something
      Z== nil || Z == :something
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  #Only if X being false does not need to be considered.
  b.report('!X ||') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times{ 
      !X || X == :something
      !Y || Y == :something
      !Z || Z == :something
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('include?') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      [nil, :something].include?(X)
      [nil, :something].include?(Y)
      [nil, :something].include?(Z)
   }            #Testloops
  }

  b.report('include? precompile') {
    testarray = [nil, :something]
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      testarray.include?(X)
      testarray.include?(Y)
      testarray.include?(Z)
   }            #Testloops
  }
} #Benchmark
```

My result:

```
                           user     system      total        real
nil? or                2.574000   0.000000   2.574000 (  2.574000)
nil? ||                2.543000   0.000000   2.543000 (  2.542800)
== nil or              2.356000   0.000000   2.356000 (  2.355600)
== nil ||              2.371000   0.000000   2.371000 (  2.371200)
!X ||                  1.856000   0.000000   1.856000 (  1.856400)
include?               4.477000   0.000000   4.477000 (  4.477200)
include? precompile    2.746000   0.000000   2.746000 (  2.745600)
```

Stefans solution in a comment seems to be the fastest.